# adding org.springframework.test package to spring-2.5.6-SEC01.jar in netbeans

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, jar

This is probably very simple, however I can't get this to work. I want to use `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTest` class which is in `org.springframework.test` package. This package is not included in Netbeans' spring library, so I want to add it. So what I have tried so far is:

- copy and paste "test" directory (downloaded from spring) into the Netbeans' spring-2.5.6-SEC01.jar file (copy it to org.springframework directory in that jar so I can use org.springframework.test to import it). If I go to project/libraries in Netbeans it is there, but when I try to import org.springframework.test.*; the autocomplition doesn't give me the option to choose test directory from org.soringframework package.
- create a new library which points to "test" directory and add it to the project- as there is no any jar file in "test" I'm not sure what path should I use to import it.

I'm pretty sure this is something very simple but I'm still a novice and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.6.SEC01), the test package is not included in `spring-2.5.6-SEC01.jar`. You need to download [spring-test-2.5.6.SEC01.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-test/2.5.6.SEC01/).

Comment: As a good habit, don't forget to push up and best solution to provide feedback for the response authors.